# Execute shell command (grunt build) with FAKE (F# make)

Tags: f#, gruntjs, f#-fake

I want to automate the build process of my project using FAKE which requires me to run a grunt task.

In particular, I want to create a target that runs the grunt build task in a subfolder of the solution folder. Due to my lack of F# knowledge, I was not able to pass multiple parameters to the static Exec method of the Shell class. https://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-processhelper-shell.html

This is what I have got so far:

```
Target "RunGrunt" (fun _ ->

      let errorCode = Shell.Exec "grunt" "build" "\Frontend"
      ()
 )
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
build.fsx(38,23): error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied
```

If I remove the last 2 parameters, it works, but fails to find grunt at runtime:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Fake.ProcessHelper.start(Process proc) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\ProcessHelper.fs:line 22
   at Fake.ProcessHelper.asyncShellExec@424-2.Invoke(Process _arg1) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\ProcessHelper.fs:line 428
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.callA@851.Invoke(AsyncParams`1 args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.commit[a](Result`1 res)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps.RunSynchronously[a](CancellationToken token, FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously[T](FSharpAsync`1 computation, FSharpOption`1 timeout, FSharpOption`1 cancellationToken)
   at FSI_0001.Build.clo@34-6.Invoke(Unit _arg5) in D:\Development\Repos\FMVEAv2\Fmvea2-frontend\build.fsx:line 36
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 483
```

Grunt is included in the path variable. (it works if called from the command line)

My questions are:

1. How can I pass multiple parameters to the Shell.Exec method?
2. How to run grunt, without including the complete path to it?

Comment: I think tuple form rather than curried form - `Shell.Exec( "grunt","build","\FrontEnd")`

Comment: Okay, this solves the first problem, thank you :)
Any advice for the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both problems are now solved.

1. [John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308206/execute-shell-command-grunt-build-with-fake-f-make?noredirect=1#comment52492278_32308206) pointed out in a comment to use tuple style instead of curried form which results in the following code:

   Shell.Exec( "grunt","build","\FrontEnd")
2. FAKE provides a method to find a file on the path. http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-processhelper.html

The target definition therefore looks like this:

```
Target "RunGrunt" (fun _ ->
    let grunt = tryFindFileOnPath if isUnix then "grunt" else "grunt.cmd"

    let errorCode = match grunt with
                      | Some g -> Shell.Exec(g, "build", "FrontEnd")
                      | None -> -1
    ()
)
```

[neftedollar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308206/execute-shell-command-grunt-build-with-fake-f-make#comment53016307_32316003) made a good point in the comments about cross platform compatiblity: Using the [EnvironmentHelper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-environmenthelper.html) to determine the platform and search for the correct executable of grunt.

Comment: for crossplatform you can use `isUnix` or other predicates from here -> http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-environmenthelper.html and then use them like `let grunt =   tryFindFileOnPath if isUnix then "grunt" else "grunt.cmd"`